# How to check if the command "php_cli" is is available on server

Tags: bash, shell

I want to execute this command from a bash script:

```
ssh ${dev_user}@${dev_url} "php_cli ${dev_path}/current/typo3cms database:export" | php typo3cms database:import
```

The Problem is that `php_cli` should only be used if its available.

I tried this but that seems not to work

```
ssh ${dev_user}@${dev_url} "if hash php_cli 2>/dev/null; then phpsrc=php_cli ; else phpsrc=php; fi && ${phpsrc} ${dev_path}/current/typo3cms database:export" | php typo3cms database:import
```

Comment: There are multiple commands which will return an error if a given command can't be found in the PATH. I never remember the pros and cons of each one, but `which` is one of them

Answer (score 0):

Is `php_cli` executable **and** in your `PATH`? If not, it will not work...

`hash` is a good way of testing commands. If you are not convinced, connect to your server via SSH and try this simple scenario in your terminal:

```
$ hash ls
$ echo $?
0
$ hash zzz
$ echo $?
1
$ hash php_cli
$ echo $?
???
```

- If you get `1` for `hash php_cli`, it means that it is not available.
- If you get `0`, `php_cli` is available.

You can then use `hash` in your automation script. For practical reasons, I would also recommend you to use **sshpass**...

Answer (score 0):

You are use

```
ssh ${dev_user}@${dev_url} " command "
```

if the command you execute on remote host between " " variable declaring there wont work. If you using ' ' variable declaring will working but local variables wont so you have to brake ' ' for local variable like: '$var1' to make both working,it is working even if you use same name for both:

```
var1=local_var
ssh ${dev_user}@${dev_url} 'hash ls 2>/dev/null && var1=php_cli1 || var1=php1 && echo 'var1'; echo $var1'
```

output:

```
local_var
php_cli1
```